# My Raspberry Pi 2 isn't connecting to the network through an Ethernet cable. What do I do?

Tags: networking

A few days ago my Raspberry Pi 2 was working perfectly, but today I turned it on and it said "no wired connection" even though my ethernet cable is connected. I tried various things such as rebooting the router and restarting the Raspberry Pi but none of that helped me.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the  the output of ifconfig.

Comment: Do you see ethernet lights on port ?

Comment: A bit more information is needed here, like what steps have you taken to troubleshoot. 
Also: I say this 200x a day here, is your powersource up to the task? (5V 2A, with a not-too-long USB cable)

Comment: Try and change the cable, plug it direct into the router with a cable that is working, not the same one (maybe you dog/cat/chinchila chomped it) - Reboot your routers/modems too. It should work

Answer (score 1):

Well if we want to go bug hunting try eliminating possibilities;

1. Save your image, reinstall Raspbian and check if your connection works now.

> yes

Problem about your Software, ask yourself if you've installed or uninstalled anything just before your last reboot.

> no

2. Problem about your Hardware or Internet connection, try another cable, does it work now?

> yes

Get a new cable.

> no

You might have fried your Pi, from this on it gets more tricky to find out what happened.

Comment: Good problem solving steps :) most likley software issue, or modem DHCP is hung up. Some reboot somewhere will fix it or cable issue...